# editing the ~/.zshrc file—how to add coloring to only directories and not the entire prompt?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I want to color only the directories and not other files like .txt etc.

Here is my current .zshrc:

```
PROMPT='%n%F{086}—%f%M %F{057}::%f %F{028}%~%f %F{057}»%f '
```

If I take away the last %f `PROMPT='%n%F{086}—%f%M %F{057}::%f %F{028}%~%f %F{057}» '` it colors all file types the same 057 color.

How can I target just the directories to apply color and set their own color apart from the 057 color?

Comment: You need to configure your version of `ls`, not your `zsh` prompt.

Comment: @chepner Why does the PROMPT variable change the color of files—when the last `%f` is taken out—using `ls`?

Comment: It's not necessarily restricted to the prompt; each instruction simply tells the terminal to display *everything* in a particular color until you change it again.

Comment: @vertexgraph : Which part in your PROMPT actually displays a **file**? I just see that you have your working directory in your prompt string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to add color to directories by editing the `ls` as according to the `man ls`

In `.zshrc` add:

`alias ls='ls -G'`

`export CLICOLOR=1`

`export LSCOLORS=gxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced`

The article [Adding Color to Your macOS “ls” Output](https://infosecmonkey.com/adding-color-to-your-macos-ls-output/) or reading through `man ls` is useful for knowing how to set which colors you want in the `LSCOLORS` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure command line file type highlighting through your prompt. What’s happening is, because you don’t reset the foreground color (`%f`), it starts to bleed into your command line.

If you want to highlight certain parts of your command line, you need to do the following:

1. Create a function.
2. In there, parse the command line for file names. You can use `words=( ${(Z+C+)BUFFER} )` to split the command line into shell words. See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags
3. Use [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to filter the shell words for different types of files. For example, `dirs=( $^words(/) )` will get you all words that are directories.
4. Use this info and the [`region_highlight` special array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting) to highlight the correct parts of the command line.
5. Finally, use [`add-zle-hook-widget`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Manipulating-Hook-Functions) to set up your function as a `line-pre-redraw` hook, so it will get called each time the command line gets redrawn.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it without installing anything extra. if not adding that last `%f` colors everything else after it, there should be a way to target specific file types for what color they should be?

Comment: I updated my answer with instructions on how to do that.